# SQL server Extension

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-extensions, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a lot of tables and for querying them I write the same code over and over again but I got to an idea to use shortcuts:

First: we have some query.customsp and can use them, but the number of those are limited

Second: create an extension to do:

For example, I have Foo  and Bar tables

I select an id from query editor and press ctrl+F it execute

```
select * from Foo where id = #selected id#
```

Or when I press ctrl+F , B it execute:

```
select * from Foo f inner join Bar b on f.id =b.foo_id where f.id= #selected_id#
```

Here is my question:

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create stored procedures on each case you need and set shortcuts for executions them.

[Customize Menus and Shortcut Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/customize-menus-and-shortcut-keys)

**Creating a Keyboard Accelerator for a Stored Procedure**

To create a keyboard accelerator for a stored procedure

1. On the **Tools** menu, click **Options**.
2. On the **Keyboard** page, select an unused keyboard combination in the
   **Shortcut** list.
3. In the **Stored Procedure** box, type the stored procedure name, and
   then click **OK**.

[image]

Comment: if you mean customsps , the number of this shrtcuts is less than 10, but I want to assign at leat a hundred of shortcuts

Comment: a hundred?! very interesting how you will remember all them ) good luck )

Comment: oh yeah, not less than 10 - there 12

Comment: Ctrl + F just select from table Foo , ctrl+F , B select from join Foo and Bar and so on ,there is no need to good memory to memorize that